# Is possible to calculate the result of my sqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xaml

I'm trying to display the percentage of the space or amount of line my XMLDOC is taking and display Inside my XAML page

```
Select Count (*) From Table 1
```

the result of my query is 107 rows return. 
Now what i want to do is to do 5000 - the result of my query which is 107 = 4893 and convert it to Percentage for eg: 107 is a 97.86% decrease of 5000.

is that possible?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to know if it is possible to display a value on a window?

Comment: Where is the number 5000 coming from?

Comment: 5000 Is the maximum line you can have and inside table1 there is 107 out 5000

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is the ExecuteScalar method in a SqlCommand object, by feeding that SQL Query into the Command and executing ExecuteScalar it'll return pretty much the [0][0] of a SQL View, meaning if you execute that query it'll return an object, and casting it to int will get you the 107 value you're looking for.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count (*) From Client_Table", connection) 
{ 
CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
};

int dataCount= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

With that you can do the required math to figure out the percentage.